# SIFT change key point scale (meaningful key point neighbourhood)

Tags: opencv, sift

I'm new to opencv and It's developing. I'm using SIFT keypoint to match two images. In order to do that i used the following code. But which provides some Error matchings.

I think  if i changed the size of key points. that would give use to get more correct key points. current size of the key point which is not adequate. Please help me to improve the `size of the key points`.

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> featureDetector = FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
    featureDetector->detect(input_right, keypoints_right);// is pointer so i used ->
    featureDetector->detect(input_left, keypoints_left);



    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> featureExtractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT");


    featureExtractor->compute(input_right, keypoints_right, descriptor_right);
    // which is pointer so i used ->
    featureExtractor->compute(input_left, keypoints_left, descriptor_left);
    // show features

    // check detected keypoints right
    Mat outputImageright;
    Scalar keypointColor = Scalar(255, 0, 0);     // Blue keypoints.
    drawKeypoints(input_right, keypoints_right, outputImageright, keypointColor, DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);

    namedWindow("Right View");
    imshow("Right View", outputImageright);


    Mat outputImageleft;
    Scalar keypointColorred = Scalar(0, 0, 255);     // Red keypoints.
    drawKeypoints(input_left, keypoints_left, outputImageleft, keypointColorred, DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);

    namedWindow("Left View");
    imshow("Left View", outputImageleft);
```

[image: output image]

Comment: Post the images (both target and test) that you're working on. I think that _changing the size of keypoints_ doesn't even make sense. Keypoints are just points, the "size" is the diameter of the meaningful keypoint neighborhood.

Comment: @Miki i have updated the image , your right by considering size of meaningful keypoint neighbourhood is that i need to be coded.

Comment: SIFT is mostly based on gradient, i.e. is subject to illumination changes. No chance they'll work here. Try using something not gradient based, like MSER.

Comment: Try MODS http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/wbs/index.html - it is very robust in matching such images.